# static css file not loaded in django

Tags: python, django, static, http-status-code-404

Help with 404 error:

```
'02/May/2018 09:41:21] "GET /static/css/design.css%25 HTTP/1.1" 404 1761'
```

The image and js files load well but not the css file. I don't know why.

My project structure:

```
--project
----templates
----project
------urls.py
------settigns.py
----app
----static
------css
------js
------images
--media
--static (after collectstatic command)
```

Settigns.py include 'django.contrib.staticfiles'

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/design.css' %}"/>
<img src="{% static 'images/slide1.jpg' %}">
```

Comment: There's a trailing '%' after your css name.

Comment: fixed !! I'm sorry, beginner's mistake. I reviewed hundred times but I did not see the %

Comment: Did that fix your issue? :)

Comment: @ThePjot yes! Fixed and working well